Flow not updating when broadcastReceiver is called
I'm new to kotlin and trying to make a reminder app for medicines for a course.
My VM doesn't react to when new names are added into the currentAlerts flow by my alarmReceiver.
The only time 'doing something' shows is when the app starts, not when a name is added to currentAlerts. Is it possible to use flows in this way or have I misunderstood them?
medicineViewModel.kt
class MedicineViewModel(
    private val dao: DatabaseDAO,
    private val alarmScheduler: AlarmScheduler,
    alarmReceiver: AlarmReceiver,
    private val userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    
    private val _currentAlerts = alarmReceiver.currentAlertsFlow

    private val _medicines = combine(dao.getMedicinesByName(), _currentAlerts) { medicines, currentAlerts ->
        Log.d("medicineViewModel", "${currentAlerts.size}")
        medicines.map { medicine ->
            Log.d("medicineViewMode", "doing something! ${medicine.name}")
            Log.d("medicineViewModel", "${medicine.name}, ${medicine.name in currentAlerts}")
            medicine.copy(isAlerting = medicine.name in currentAlerts)
        }
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())

    private val _preferences = userPreferencesRepository.getActivated().stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        UserPreferences(activated = false)
    )

    //_state håller koll på allt som visas på skärmen.
    private val _state =
        MutableStateFlow(MedicineState()) // Starta ett nytt flow utifrån MedicineState (börjar tomt)

    // _state är allting som visas på skärmen. Man hämtar medicinerna via DAO och stoppar in det i "medicines" i state.
    // Allting innan .stateIn är instruktioner för när man börjar löpande hämta data. MedicineState() i stateIn är
    // utgångspunkten, alltså en tom skärm.
    val state = combine(_state, _medicines, _preferences) { state, medicines, preferences ->
        state.copy(
            medicines = medicines,
            preferences = preferences,
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), MedicineState())

        fun onEvent(event: MedicineEvent) {
            when (event) {
               ...
           }
        }

    fun calculateAlarms() {
        for (medicine in state.value.medicines) {

            val alarmItem = AlarmItem(
                medicineName = medicine.name,
                time = LocalDateTime.now()
                    .plusMinutes(medicine.interval.toLong())
            )

            alarmItem.let(alarmScheduler::schedule)

        }
    }
}

alarmReceiver.kt
package com.example.myapplication.model.alarm

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow

class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    // MutableStateFlow to hold the latest list of alerts
    private val _currentAlertsFlow = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf<String>())
    val currentAlertsFlow: StateFlow<MutableList<String>> get() = _currentAlertsFlow

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "alarm triggered!")
        val message = intent?.getStringExtra("medicineName") ?: return
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Alarm triggered: $message")

        // Update the alerts list and emit the new list
//        val updatedAlerts = _currentAlertsFlow.value.toMutableList()
//        updatedAlerts.add(message)
//        _currentAlertsFlow.value = updatedAlerts
        _currentAlertsFlow.value.add(message)
    }
}

Thanks for reading!

What you are doing is basically correct. There is just one major issue: StateFlows only notify their observers when a new value is set. That's not what you do, though:
_currentAlertsFlow.value.add(message)

This only modifies the already existing value. What already should be best practise would in this case have prevented this error from surfacing in the first place: Make your state objects immutable. The content of _currentAlertsFlow should have the type List<String>, not MutableList<String>.
The AlarmReceiver should look something like this:
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val _currentAlertsFlow = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<String>())
    val currentAlertsFlow: StateFlow<List<String>> get() = _currentAlertsFlow

    override fun onReceive(...) {
        // ..
        _currentAlertsFlow.update { it + message }
    }
}

Now, whenever onReceive is called, a new list is created and set for the flow's value. That is recognized by the StateFlow so it notifies everything that is downstream that a new value is present and the other flows will update accordingly.
Btw., your intermediate flows do not need to be StateFlows, you can remove the stateIn. Only the latest flow, the flow that is publicly exposed in the view model, needs to be a StateFlow (and all other flows that need to represent a state, of course).
